# Mongodb: unwind, lookup, group. Нужно оставить/добавить поле из исходного документа

Tags: mongodb, агрегация, aggregate

Выполняю такой запрос с целью привязки ссылок из коллекции `files` по полю `origin` к коллекции `goods` (`$match` использую для обкатки):

```
db.goods.aggregate([
  { "$match": {_id: ObjectId("5ad5d9cddae56f1bfe74c831")}},
  { "$unwind": "$Software" },
  {
    $lookup:
      {
        from: "files",
        localField: "Software.file",
        foreignField: "origin",
        as: "files"
      }
  },
  { $group:
    {
      _id: "$_id",
      Software:
        {
          $push:
            {
              name: "$Software.nameSKU",
              file: {"$arrayElemAt": ["$files.pathName", 0]}
            }
        }
    }
  }
]);
```

Получаю следующий результат:

[image: mongo unwind, lookup, group]

Таким образом, я переписываю субдокумент `Software` на то, что мне нужно.

Вопрос: я хочу добавить субдокумент `Advantages` из исходного документа (все равно идет группировка: `_id: "$_id"`), но без использования агрегации.

Другими словами:

```
  Advantages: "$Advantages"
```

Если засунуть в `$group`, такая конструкция не работает. Думаю, либо рядом с `$lookup` что-то делать, либо потом еще раз "объединять". Может быть есть правильный способ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решается оператором `$first` в секции `$group`:

```
Advantages: {
  $first: "$Advantages"
}
```

Итоговый запрос:

```
    db.goods.aggregate([
      { "$match": {_id: ObjectId("5ad5d9cddae56f1bfe74c831")}},
      { "$unwind": "$Software" },
      {
        $lookup:
          {
            from: "files",
            localField: "Software.file",
            foreignField: "origin",
            as: "files"
          }
      },
      { $group:
        {
          _id: "$_id",
          Advantages: 
            {
              $first: "$Advantages"
            },
          Software:
            {
              $push:
                {
                  name: "$Software.nameSKU",
                  file: {"$arrayElemAt": ["$files.pathName", 0]}
                }
            }
        }
      }
    ]);
```

Результат:

[image: aggregate, unwind, lookup, group, first]