# MongoDB. Документы с одинаковыми ObjectId в разных коллекциях

Tags: mongodb

Есть две коллекции в которых есть документы с одинаковыми id:

```
db.coll_1.insert({_id: ObjectId("1"), name: 'Article name'}); 
db.coll_2.insert({_id: ObjectId("1"), name: 'Blog name'});
```

Как при вставке документа ссылаться на эти id?
Ведь запись

```
db.coll_3.insert({_id: ObjectId("5"), post_id: ObjectId("1"), name: 'Name'})
```

неверна

Хорошая ли это практика использовать такие id в MongoDB?

Comment: Смысл идентификатора в том и заключается, чтобы он был уникальным. Одинаковые идентификаторы - это уже не идентификаторы, а имена.

Comment: в реляционных базах данных идентификаторы уникальны на уровне таблиц. Я не понимаю почему в MongoDB они должны быть уникальны на уровне всей базы?

Comment: Вам уже ответили - они не **должны**. Но если что-то не запрещено, это ещё не значит что так делать нужно. Id крайне не рекомендуется назначать вручную, потому что они генерируются по тому же принципу, что и UUID, и только так вы можете быть уверены что коллизий нигде не случится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заранее генерировать ObjectId не рекомендуется, но возможно. Уникальность должна быть на уровне коллекции:

```
db.coll_1.insert({_id: ObjectId("5aac37fdbb529e515dc796f3")});
db.coll_2.insert({_id: ObjectId("5aac37fdbb529e515dc796f3")});
```

Все вставилось успешно:

```
> db.coll_1.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5aac37fdbb529e515dc796f3") }
> db.coll_2.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5aac37fdbb529e515dc796f3") }
```

У вас не вставилось по причине того, что _id слишком короткий.

Почему нужно избегать вставки своих _id:

[ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/|ObjectId) хранит следующее:

- дату в формате Unix => вы всегда знаете, когда был создан документ, даже если это не закладывалось в схему
- случайное число
- счетчик, начинающийся со случайного значения

Рано или поздно может потребоваться слить коллекции. А глобально не уникальный _id не даст его сделать. Переименовать? А если на документ установлены ссылки в сотнях других коллекций?

Где-то читал, что если делается распределенная система, то в качестве "начальное значения счетчика" можно указать номер сервера помноженного на 10000, например, и это полностью исключит возникновение коллизий на огромных распределенных базах. Ведь есть не нулевая вероятность, что дата, случайное число, и счетчик могут случайно совпасть на двух серверах. А таким способом мы "выделяем" диапазоны _id под конкретный сервер

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но как тогда при вставке документа ссылаться на id в других коллекциях?

Comment: @MyNick при вставке можно дождаться получения _id и использовать его далее, например так: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/964656/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-id-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2-mongodb/964856#964856

Comment: Хорошо. А как в MongoDB лучше хранить внешние ключи, в разных коллекциях или все в одной?

Comment: @MyNick, Mongo это не РСУБД, чтобы делать таблицы связки. Зачастую вообще ссылки не нужны, сразу в документе хранят поддокумент. А ссылку можно в этой же коллекции хранить. А для соединения использовать [$lookup](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/818018/mongodb-unwind-lookup-group-%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5)

Comment: Спасибо большое